# Angular Calander header with extra column

Tags: angular, calendar

I have used mattlewis92's angular calendar (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) in my angular application.

I would like to add one more columns to the left side of the date displayed.Please find the attached picture for the same.
[Calendar requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYhMq.jpg).

Can any one  please help to achieve this?

```js
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef, OnInit, EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  addHours,
  startOfMonth,
  subWeeks,
  addWeeks,
  endOfMonth,
  startOfWeek,
  endOfWeek
} from 'date-fns';


import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  CalendarEvent,
  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,
  CalendarView,
  CalendarUtils,
  CalendarMonthViewDay
} from 'angular-calendar';
import { GetMonthViewArgs, MonthView, WeekDay, DAYS_OF_WEEK } from 'calendar-utils';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3'
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF'
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA'
  }
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-taskmanger',
    templateUrl: './taskmanger.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./taskmanger.component.css']
})

  export class TaskmangerComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
              private datePipe: DatePipe, 
              ) {}


    clickedDate: Date;


      // view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;
    view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Week;


    CalendarView = CalendarView;

    viewDate: Date = new Date();

    selectedDay: WeekDay;

    refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    
        ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    dayClicked({ date }: { date: Date }): void {
      this.clickedDate = date
      if (this.view === CalendarView.Month) 
      {
        this.viewDate = date; 
        this.view = CalendarView.Week;
      }
    }

    //Setting the calender view
    setView(view: CalendarView) {
      this.view = view;
      console.log(this.view);
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="btn btn-dark"  mwlCalendarPreviousView [view]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (click)="previousWeekData()">
                  Previous
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary" mwlCalendarToday [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (click)="todaysWeekData()">
                  Today
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark" mwlCalendarNextView [view]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (click)="nextWeekData()">
                  Next
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h3>{{  viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en':weekStartsOn }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="btn btn-dark" (click)="setView(CalendarView.Month)" (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Month">
                    Month
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark" (click)="setView(CalendarView.Week)" [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Week">
                    Week
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <br />
          <div [ngSwitch]="view">
            
            <mwl-calendar-month-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month" [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" [refresh]="refresh" (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)">
            </mwl-calendar-month-view>
            
            <mwl-calendar-week-view Task *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week" [events]=""  [weekStartsOn]="0" [viewDate]="viewDate" [refresh]="refresh" >
            </mwl-calendar-week-view>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add extra column(WIth multiple rows..?) as editable?

Comment: Yes, i want to add an extra column with a heading . Heading is static.

Comment: As of now I did like this(link) " https://ibb.co/646XnxL ". I just added extra column(div) alongside calendar(div).

Comment: i also did the same.

Comment: Then what was the problem? I think we can't add directly to the calendar because it is third party dependency right?

Comment: I was trying to add directly to the calendar, but it want working. So i tried adding it outside and using css placed it in proper place.

Comment: @sarasm , did you get any solution to your problem, even I have same requirement.

Comment: I solved it by adding the column outside the calendar and aligned it properly using CSS